# Peculiar JavaScript date comparison output

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Can someone explain why subtracting one JavaScript date from another, where both dates are set to midnight, do not always return consistent results?

For example, see the following:

```
// the number of milliseconds in 1 day ...
var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 

// this line returns 1, as I would expect, as there is 1 day between the 2 dates ...
// (26th March and 27th March)
var days1 = (new Date(2016, 2, 27) - new Date(2016, 2, 26)) / msInDay;

// but this line returns 0.9583333333333334
// (27th March and 28 March)
var days2 = (new Date(2016, 2, 28) - new Date(2016, 2, 27)) / msInDay;
```

Why doesn't days2 == 1 as well?

Comment: daylight savings time kicks in/out on the last sunday of march?

Comment: It is equal to 1.  I just tried your exact code in my Chrome console.

Comment: @JaromandaX - bingo! it's daylight savings. obvious now you mention it.

Comment: @Nicholas - if you set your locale to en_GB you will probably see the issue

Comment: @GwynHowell - Ah, you are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript (actually ECMAScript) Date objects use a time value that is UTC. When creating date objects with the Date constructor, the system time zone offset is taken into account when creating the time value so it is offset by the time zone offset for the particular date.

If you want to calculate the days between two dates without daylight saving errors, bypass the time zone offset by setting the UTC time value directly, e.g.

```js
var days = (new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 2, 28)) - new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 2, 27))) / 8.64e7;

document.write(days);
```

Alternatively, just round the returned value if daylight saving is the only difference between the two time zones.

#### Edit

If just the difference in days is required, then:

```
(Date.UTC(2016, 2, 28) - Date.UTC(2016, 2, 27)) / 8.64e7
```

is sufficient.

PS. 
A language designator like en-gb should not be used to represent a time zone.
"Locale" is also inappropriate as it refers to a generally small area defined by a geographical feature or habitation, whereas time zones are generally very large areas based roughly on lines of longitude that have no reference to geography other than where they might be coincident with administrative boundaries.

Comment: Top tip on the Date.UTC method. Thanks